# "as claimed by" is it appropriate to be used?

Tags: synonyms, politeness

I am doing a literature review on cocoa demand and supply. The norm is cocoa demand is going up slightly. However, I was reading an article stating:

> Demand for cocoa is predicted to rise by 30% by 2020 but without
> empowering and investing in small-scale farmers, the industry will
> struggle to provide sufficient supply.

Is it appropriate to say

> The demand for cocoa was predicted to increase by 30% by 2020 as claimed by .... (2020).

I have used 'according to' several times now and thought to change it.

Comment: *... [according to, as stated by/in, as claimed by] ...* followed by a source/company/study/investigation, but not a year.

Comment: I think you could simply put a parenthetical citation after "2020 (...), but..." It will be understood that the information or claim comes from that source.

Comment: yes.. I have to put the in-text citation -> "as claimed by Beg (2020)."

Comment: I don't think **as claimed by** is *wrong* exactly, but why do you want to use such a complicated phrasing?  Why not just say "...was predicted to rise **by Joe Schmoe**"?

Comment: @stangdon just another way of saying *according to*. Yeah, it is a bit complicated I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Original Article

> Demand for cocoa **is** predicted to rise by 30% **by** 2020 but without empowering and investing in small-scale farmers, the industry will struggle to provide sufficient supply.

Your Suggested Review Report

> The demand for cocoa **was** predicted to increase by 30% by 2020 as claimed by .... (2020).

'As claimed by' can be used instead of 'according to' in your literature review report.

I note that you have changed the copula from **is** to **was**, and this is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think it is less polite to use "as claimed by". I do not know why I have the feeling that it is a bit less polite Lol

Comment: I do not think it is impolite to use 'as claimed by'.